# Microsoft's App-V licensing

Tags: appv

I am trying to understand how the Mictosoft's App-V licensing works and I was hoping that someone who has gone through this can provide some info on the topic.

Do I need to buy separate RDS licenses?

My understanding is that the TechNet and MSDN subscriptions only give you a development license.  If this is the case, how do I purchase a production license?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Microsoft Licensing Support. If you have questions about MS licenses or costs, contact Microsoft. They would also be the ones to ask about your purchasing options.

Comment: @KenWhite Noted.  I understand your point.  I was just asking if anyone has done this and if so to share their experience.

Comment: That's not how this site works. An off-topic question is an off-topic question, no matter how much you hope it will help you to ask here. The [help] has more information about the types of question that are on-topic here; MS licensing and pricing isn't among them.